# Installing chrome in Centos 6.2 (Final)

Tags: centos, yum, installation, google-chrome, centos6.2

I need to install chrome in a dedicated centos server where I only access via ssh, it doesn't have X or any windows graphical stuff.

I need it to be able to pack extensions using `google-chrome --pack-extension`.

I tried adding this to `/etc/yum.repos.d/google.repo`

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 32-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

And then `yum install google-chrome-stable`, but there's a huge list of dependencies problems:

**How can I install chrome without breaking anything else?**

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I installed perl-CGI from .rpm because yum couldn't find it, now dependencies resolve and it show me this list of packages to install:

```
Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                         Arch                                        Version                                                                Repository                                          Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 google-chrome-stable                                            x86_64                                      19.0.1084.52-138391                                                    google-chrome                                       35 M
Installing for dependencies:
 ConsoleKit                                                      x86_64                                      0.4.1-3.el6                                                            base                                                82 k
 ConsoleKit-libs                                                 x86_64                                      0.4.1-3.el6                                                            base                                                17 k
 GConf2                                                          x86_64                                      2.28.0-6.el6                                                           base                                               964 k
 ORBit2                                                          x86_64                                      2.14.17-3.1.el6                                                        base                                               168 k
 bc                                                              x86_64                                      1.06.95-1.el6                                                          base                                               110 k
 cdparanoia-libs                                                 x86_64                                      10.2-5.1.el6                                                           base                                                47 k
 cups                                                            x86_64                                      1:1.4.2-44.el6_2.3                                                     updates                                            2.3 M
 dbus                                                            x86_64                                      1:1.2.24-5.el6_1                                                       base                                               207 k
 desktop-file-utils                                              x86_64                                      0.15-9.el6                                                             base                                                47 k
 ed                                                              x86_64                                      1.1-3.3.el6                                                            base                                                72 k
 eggdbus                                                         x86_64                                      0.6-3.el6                                                              base                                                91 k
 foomatic                                                        x86_64                                      4.0.4-1.el6_1.1                                                        base                                               251 k
 foomatic-db                                                     noarch                                      4.0-7.20091126.el6                                                     base                                               980 k
 foomatic-db-filesystem                                          noarch                                      4.0-7.20091126.el6                                                     base                                               4.4 k
 foomatic-db-ppds                                                noarch                                      4.0-7.20091126.el6                                                     base                                                19 M
 ghostscript                                                     x86_64                                      8.70-11.el6_2.6                                                        updates                                            4.4 M
 ghostscript-fonts                                               noarch                                      5.50-23.1.el6                                                          base                                               751 k
 gstreamer                                                       x86_64                                      0.10.29-1.el6                                                          base                                               764 k
 gstreamer-plugins-base                                          x86_64                                      0.10.29-1.el6                                                          base                                               942 k
 gstreamer-tools                                                 x86_64                                      0.10.29-1.el6                                                          base                                                23 k
 iso-codes                                                       noarch                                      3.16-2.el6                                                             base                                               2.4 M
 lcms-libs                                                       x86_64                                      1.19-1.el6                                                             base                                               100 k
 libIDL                                                          x86_64                                      0.8.13-2.1.el6                                                         base                                                83 k
 libXScrnSaver                                                   x86_64                                      1.2.0-1.el6                                                            base                                                19 k
 libXfont                                                        x86_64                                      1.4.1-2.el6_1                                                          base                                               128 k
 libXv                                                           x86_64                                      1.0.5-1.el6                                                            base                                                21 k
 libfontenc                                                      x86_64                                      1.0.5-2.el6                                                            base                                                24 k
 libgudev1                                                       x86_64                                      147-2.40.el6                                                           base                                                59 k
 libmng                                                          x86_64                                      1.0.10-4.1.el6                                                         base                                               165 k
 libogg                                                          x86_64                                      2:1.1.4-2.1.el6                                                        base                                                21 k
 liboil                                                          x86_64                                      0.3.16-4.1.el6                                                         base                                               121 k
 libtheora                                                       x86_64                                      1:1.1.0-2.el6                                                          base                                               129 k
 libvisual                                                       x86_64                                      0.4.0-9.1.el6                                                          base                                               135 k
 libvorbis                                                       x86_64                                      1:1.2.3-4.el6_2.1                                                      updates                                            168 k
 mailx                                                           x86_64                                      12.4-6.el6                                                             base                                               234 k
 man                                                             x86_64                                      1.6f-29.el6                                                            base                                               263 k
 mesa-libGLU                                                     x86_64                                      7.11-3.el6                                                             base                                               201 k
 nvidia-graphics195.30-libs                                      x86_64                                      195.30-120.el6                                                         atrpms                                              13 M
 openjpeg-libs                                                   x86_64                                      1.3-7.el6                                                              base                                                59 k
 pax                                                             x86_64                                      3.4-10.1.el6                                                           base                                                69 k
 phonon-backend-gstreamer                                        x86_64                                      1:4.6.2-20.el6                                                         base                                               125 k
 polkit                                                          x86_64                                      0.96-2.el6_0.1                                                         base                                               158 k
 poppler                                                         x86_64                                      0.12.4-3.el6_0.1                                                       base                                               557 k
 poppler-data                                                    noarch                                      0.4.0-1.el6                                                            base                                               2.2 M
 poppler-utils                                                   x86_64                                      0.12.4-3.el6_0.1                                                       base                                                73 k
 portreserve                                                     x86_64                                      0.0.4-4.el6_1.1                                                        base                                                22 k
 qt                                                              x86_64                                      1:4.6.2-20.el6                                                         base                                               4.0 M
 qt-sqlite                                                       x86_64                                      1:4.6.2-20.el6                                                         base                                                50 k
 qt-x11                                                          x86_64                                      1:4.6.2-20.el6                                                         base                                                12 M
 qt3                                                             x86_64                                      3.3.8b-30.el6                                                          base                                               3.5 M
 redhat-lsb                                                      x86_64                                      4.0-3.el6.centos                                                       base                                                24 k
 redhat-lsb-graphics                                             x86_64                                      4.0-3.el6.centos                                                       base                                                12 k
 redhat-lsb-printing                                             x86_64                                      4.0-3.el6.centos                                                       base                                                11 k
 sgml-common                                                     noarch                                      0.6.3-32.el6                                                           base                                                43 k
 time                                                            x86_64                                      1.7-37.1.el6                                                           base                                                26 k
 tmpwatch                                                        x86_64                                      2.9.16-4.el6                                                           base                                                31 k
 xdg-utils                                                       noarch                                      1.0.2-17.20091016cvs.el6                                               base                                                58 k
 xml-common                                                      noarch                                      0.6.3-32.el6                                                           base                                               9.5 k
 xorg-x11-font-utils                                             x86_64                                      1:7.2-11.el6                                                           base                                                75 k
 xz                                                              x86_64                                      4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6                                       base                                               137 k
 xz-lzma-compat                                                  x86_64                                      4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6                                       base                                                16 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install      62 Package(s)
```

**Is it safe to continue and install all that or could I break something already installed?**

Comment: Why? What good is a browser on a headless cli-only server?

Comment: @ErikA 'I need it to be able to pack extensions using google-chrome --pack-extension.'

Answer (score 4):

You're going to be very hard pressed to find a pre-built copy of chrome that doesn't depend on world+dog, because let's face it -- the number of people who *aren't* going to want a GUI copy of a web browser is really, really small.

Assuming that Chrome even *can* be built without GUI dependencies (quite a sizeable ask), you're pretty guaranteed to have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is mentions of x86_64, I imagine you have a 64bit version of CentOS installed. Try using `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64` instead. Then `yum clean all`. Then try installing chrome.

Your old post said

> Packages skipped because of dependency problems

But it now says

> Dependencies Resolved.

It is safe to install, since it is not updating any packages. Even then, it would be relatively safe.

Comment: Thanks, this is a new server and i always used 32b so I didn't notice that. i tried with the x64 version but i still get the same huge dependencies error list.